# Django is printing month name in english even when LANGUAGE_CODE is 'es-CO'

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I've a Django project where I'm trying to render the month name inside a template with the `date` template tag.

In my `settings.py` I've the following because this app runs in Colombia (should be in spanish)

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es-CO'
USE_L10N = True
```

In the template I'm trying to format the date this way:

```
{{ car.expiration_date|date:'F' }}
```

According with the documentation the `F` returns the month's full name and that's true but is coming in english instead of spanish.

I have other Django projects working properly with these settings but I can't find the reason because this one isn't.

Comment: Not sure `es-CO` is a valid locale. Try using `es`. Check this to see the list of locales directly from the source code: https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/conf/locale

Comment: `es-CO` is a valid locale according to the Django documentation where they share this link http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html

Comment: That is not the Django documentation. That's the RCF that specifies the overall valid locales, but not the ones specific to Django. What I meant by my comment above, is that Django doesn't have a translation for your specific locale, only for the ones in the link I posted. Try using the `es` locale (or one that's closest to what you want) and it will probably work.

Comment: Ah, ok @EduardLuca, I've tested with just `es` but didn't worked for this particular template.

Comment: I'm out of ideas then, sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have no other way of setting the language code for this particular template, you could try to render the date in your email templateby switching to the right language:

```
{% load i18n %}

{% language 'es-co' %} {{ car.expiration_date|date:'F' }} {% endlanguage %}
```

See [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#switching-language-in-templates)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

- to restart the server
- pip freeze to check the Django version => double check that there is no change

  - maybe USE_I18N // USE_L10N
- a search on LANGUAGE_CODE in your code just in case

This in a view somewhere or in the Django shell just to to be sure:

```
from django.conf import settings
print settings.LANGUAGE_CODE
print settings. …
```

Comment: I've tried what you sent and I got the surprise that in the homepage of this application a datetime object I'm sending to the template is being printed in spanish.

I got so much confused than before.

Comment: what? what did you try? Do you mean it's only working in the homepage?

Comment: I'm printing the `settings.LANGUAGE_CODE` inside my homepage's view to test and it's `es-CO` as expected. The template where I'm having the problem is an email and I'm using the `render_to_string` function to render the email body html.

Comment: That was missing from your question ! render_to_string(…, context_instance = RequestContext(request))

Comment: Yes! You're right! I had only thought about it even I was writing that comment. But the method that sends the email is a Model method that hasn't access to the request object.

Comment: I guess you can instantiate one (I haven't tried). I personally like to keep my model simple and wouldn't put email sending there. Also, any reason why you cannot simply pass the request as a parameter?